# SQL Get specific columns from one table and all rows from a joined table in one query

Tags: subquery, join, sql

This may have been asked before and I just can't find it.

I have a one to many relationship in the database on a few tables.

- table1
- table2
- table3

table2 - table3 is the 1-many relationship

here's a mock of what I have:

```
select
table1.id
table1.Column
table2.Column2
-- I want all entries here from table 3 here as well
From table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID
left outer join join table3 t3 on t3.ID2 = t2.ID2
```

Is it possible to also select all of the entries that belong to table3 in this query without specifying a sub-query in the select statement?

Also, does this look right? As I've said in the past I'm really new to SQL, thus my sucky code...

**EDIT**

Sorry guys I misspoke. I need a single column from each of the rows that should be in table3

```
select
table1.id,
table1.Column,
table2.Column2,
-- I'm going to need a subquery here aren't I...?
table3.columnFromRrow1,
table3.columnFromRrow2,
table3.columnFromRrow3
From table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID
left outer join join table3 t3 on t3.ID2 = t2.ID2
```

Comment: From your edit it now looks like you need a Pivot. Are there always 3 rows in table3? What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2005, I think there can be more than 3 rows, but I'm not sure I care. The client only asked for the top 3.

Comment: Ordered by the ID table3.ID2 works for me. Requirements were not very specific... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS
     ( SELECT table1.t1id,
              table1.t1col,
              table2.t2col,
              table3.t3col,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1id,t1col,t2col 
                                 ORDER BY table3.id) AS RN
     FROM     table1 t1
              LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
              ON       t2.ID = t1.ID
              LEFT OUTER JOIN
              JOIN table3 t3
              ON       t3.ID2 = t2.ID2
     )
SELECT 
   t1id,
   t1col,
   t2col,
   MAX(CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN t3col END) AS columnFromRrow1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN RN=2 THEN t3col END) AS columnFromRrow2,
   MAX(CASE WHEN RN=3 THEN t3col END) AS columnFromRrow3
FROM cte
WHERE RN<=3
GROUP BY t1id,t1col,t2col
```

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I want. I see it took a little tricky SQL  magic to get it done. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've modified (and corrected your query to do what you want).

```
SELECT 
  table1.id,
  table1.Column,
  table2.Column2, 
  table3.* -- All columns from table3
FROM table1 AS t1 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS t2 
       ON t2.ID = t1.ID 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 AS t3 
       ON t3.ID2 = t2.ID2
```

**NOTE: This answer is no longer valid, because the original question has been modified...**

Answer (score -1):

Using *

```
select
table1.id
table1.Column
table2.Column2
-- I want all entries here from table 3 here as well
table3.*
From table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID
left outer join join table3 t3 on t3.ID2 = t2.ID2
```

Comment: Use of the * in a production query is an extremely poor programming practice.